# Show more if checkbox is checked with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

what I'm trying to do is set up a form, that shows different checkboxes. If a checkbox is checked some additional checkboxes should show up below and ALL should be checked automatically until the user unchecks them. If the user unchecks the inital checkbox all checkboxes should hide again and uncheck!

My form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @cr do |f| %>

        <%= f.association :design, as: :check_boxes, label: false, collection: Design.find(1) %>
          <div id="sub_design" style="display:none;">
            <%= f.association :wngs, as: :check_boxes, label: false %>               
          </div>

<% end %>
```

I found various scripts but noone of them does what I need and I'm totally bad with javascripts.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for a solution like below

You have a checkbox called `ParentCheckBox` with id `myParentCheckbox` and the submenu grouped by a div as shown below

HTML :

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myParentCheckbox" name="ParentCheckBox" > ParentCheckBox</input>
    <div id="mySubMenu">
        <input type="checkbox" class="mySubCheckBox" name="ParentCheckBox"> SubCheckBox1</input>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mySubCheckBox" name="ParentCheckBox"> SubCheckBox2</input>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mySubCheckBox" name="ParentCheckBox"> SubCheckBox3</input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now on selecting the `ParentCheckBox` the `mySubMenu` with the 3 check boxes will be selected and on deselecting the `ParentCheckBox`  the `mySubMenu` with 3 check boxes will be hidden with the check boxes inside the  `mySubMenu` unchecked.

JS :

```
$("#myParentCheckbox").on("click",function() {
    if($("#myParentCheckbox").is(":checked")) {
        console.log("parent box checked");
        //show the subboxes checked        
        $("#mySubMenu").show();
        $("#mySubMenu .mySubCheckBox").prop("checked",true);

    }
    else {
        console.log("parent box unchecked");
        // uncheck the sub boxes and hide it        
        $("#mySubMenu .mySubCheckBox").prop("checked",false);
        $("#mySubMenu").hide();
    }
});
```

Refer Fiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hbpzkye9/1/)

Comment: The demo looks perfectly fine. But not sure how I can use it with my simpleform. I will try around a little and tell you if it works. Thanks alot!

Comment: Cool always there to help

Comment: Okay, I think its not working properly with IE8. Tested the demo only with firefox cause IE 8 cant open fiddle. Any idea how to make it work with IE 8?

Comment: Which version of Jquery you are using ?